# RDD creation and variable binding

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lazy-evaluation

I have a very simple code:

```py
def fun(x, n):
    return (x, n)

rdds = []
for i in range(2):
    rdd = sc.parallelize(range(5*i, 5*(i+1)))
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: fun(x, i))
    rdds.append(rdd)

a = sc.union(rdds)
print a.collect()
```

I had expected the output to be the following:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

However, the output is the following:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]
```

This is bewildering, to say the least.

It seems, due to lazy evaluation of RDDs, the value of `i` that is being used to create RDDs is the one it bears when `collect()` is called, which is 1 (from the last run of the `for` loop).

Now, both elements of the tuple are derived from `i`.

But it seems, for the first element of the tuple, `i` bears values 0 and 1  while for the second element of the tuple `i` bears the value 2.

Can somebody please explain what's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: fun(x, i))
```

to

```
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x, i=i: (x, i))
```

That is only about Python, look at this

> https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Comment: So `i=i` pushes `i` into the scope of lambda function and when it's called the local value of lambda function will be accessed first.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi  yes. The default values are evaluated at the point of function definition in the defining scope

Comment: The id of `0` and `1` integer objects in the `list` created by `range(2)` is assigned to the lambda function arguments. That list won't be garbage collected because the items inside it is still being pointed by some other variables?

Answer (score 0):

`sc.parallelize()` is an action which will be executed instantly. So both the values of `i` i.e `0` and `1` will be used.

But in case of `rdd.map()` only the last value of `i` will be used when you call `collect()` later.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(5*i, 5*(i+1)))
rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: fun(x, i))
```

Here rdd.map wont transform the rdd, it will just create DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph), i.e lambda function will not be applied to elements of rdd.

When you call collect(), then the lambda function will be called but by that time `i` has a value of 1. If you reassign `i=10` before calling collect then that value of `i` will be used.

Comment: If this is the case, then why are values 0 and 1 being used for the first element of the tuple, while only 1 for the second element in my example? Thanks.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni Because sc.parallelize() is an action which will be executed instantly while rdd.map() is a transformation. If you collect the rdd inside the loop and then append to list then you will get your desired result.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni You make take zhangtong's solution, where he is pushing down the value of `i` into the lambda function's scope. So when the lambda function is called, it will use it's local value of `i` first before climbing up into outer scope where the value of `i` has changed.